# Can I mount my local (OSX) directory to a remote linux host during my SSH session?

Tags: linux, macos, ssh

I spend a lot of time using SSH.  While using Vagrant, I've found that having a shared folder between my local machine and the guest that I can access from the guest really makes life easier.

Is there a way to do this with plain-old-SSH?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [SSHFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS). It allows you to mount a directory from a remote host over ssh on your local system.

Comment: I'd rather have my *local* folder shared to my *guest*.  These are resources I want to disappear from the guest when I complete my session.  Mounting the *guest* to my *local* would leave those resources on the *guest*, correct?

Comment: Once on the guest, try establishing an sshfs connection _back_ to your personal (local) machine (assuming it's not so firewalled that you can't ssh from guest to your personal machine)